# Google Calendar API Python Documentation

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

Is there anywhere out there that has documentation of the methods and classes used in the Google Calendar API (or any other Google API)? I know the REST documentation has example code, but I'd like a nice convenient place where I can read about all of the options for a particular method. For instance, I'm trying to use the

```
gdata.calendar.service.CalendarEventQuery('default', 'private', 'full')
```

method, but I want it to include both public and private entries. I have no idea how I would do that, because the google examples don't explain what the alternatives are to 'private' and 'full.' I know I could open the code in the library, but I was hoping for a more convenient resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the PyDocs at:

https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/

They're available for each API.

**Edit:** just realized your'e using the old GData library and an old version of Calendar API. You really should update to Calendar v3 and the [Google API Python Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/).

Regarding public vs. private. The private feed should include all public data of the calendar. Private means that information visible only to the calendar owner will be included.

Answer (score 0):

I had a some difficulty figuring out how to use the google calendar api with OAuth etc.  I finally got everything working and along the way I wrote a very simple easy to use package.  I posted it to github and it can be installed from pypi using "pip install gback".  The documentation has instructions for google account settings also.

https://github.com/Schwarzschild/gback

For example you can list all your calendars with this snippit:

```
>>> from gback import GCalSession
>>> session = GCalSession('~/gback.oauth')
>>>
>>> for c in session.names: print c
```

The documentation has more examples.

Enjoy,
Marc